# inline bootstrap datepicker date range

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Good morning ! :)

I have included a bootstrap datepicker like this:

[image]

If the user click on a date I get the selected Date.

```
$('.date-inline').on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    alert( $(".date-inline").data('datepicker') )
});
```

Now I would like to realize that the user can select a date range.
the user should select a start and an end date > the datepicker highlights the dates between start and end date and I get the range as a result.

Is this possible?
If yes, how? :)

**UPDATE**

The user click on 13 April (first date) and on 19 April (second date)
The datepicker should now shows the the dates between the selected dates as "selected" (selected = background color blue, like the "19" in the screenshot above)

And I would like to know, which dates are selected (for example in array)
The values for this example are:

```
2020-04-13, 2020-04-14, 2020-04-15, 2020-04-16, 2020-04-17, 2020-04-18, 2020-04-19
```

Comment: `I would like to realize that the user can select a date range. the user should select a start and an end date` show us how will he select the date range and that too after that `the datepicker highlights the dates between start and end date and I get the range as a result.` hightlighting date range and outputting it ??? how would you want you to see

Comment: and also provide code for it or minimal explanation to solve it

Comment: please look at my first post. there are more information

Comment: see answer below its working and  possibly give it a green tick as community members will get help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
    var currentDate1 =new Date($( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "getDate" ));
  var currentDate2 = new Date($( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker( "getDate" ));
    $( "#datepicker3" ).datepicker({
      minDate:new Date(currentDate1),
      maxDate:new Date(currentDate2)
      });
    }
});


  } );

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date1: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<p>Date2: <input type="text" id="datepicker2" ></p>
<p>Date3: <input type="text" id="datepicker3"></p> 
</body>
</html>
```

have a look at it running:https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/ow20pzdk/127/

Thanks!!!!  :-)